# Bootstrap select giving inaccurate value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap select dropdown in html:

```
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleSelect1">Number of vegan meals</label>
            <select id="week2veganquantity" class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
```

It works, but when I go to select the value like so:

`$("#week2veganquantity.form-control").find("option:selected").text()`;

will return:

```
"11"
```

If I have "1" selected, it diplayse "11" in the console If I have "2" selected, it displays "12" if I print in the console.

If the value is "01" then "101" is returned.

Has anyone seen this? What's happening here? How do I fix it.

Comment: Please write the Log print code too.

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I don't understand why this got a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  Maybe try setting the value for your options.  It's more reliable since the text is used for display purposes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("#week2veganquantity.form-control").find("option:selected").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleSelect1">Number of vegan meals</label>
  <select id="week2veganquantity" class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
    <option value="1">1 - one</option>
    <option value="2">2 - two</option>
    <option value="3">3 - three</option>
    <option value="4" selected>4 - four</option>
    <option value="5">5 - five</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that your select has two id's.

```
id="week2veganquantity" 
id="exampleSelect1"
```

An element should really only have one id.  This got me wondering if there might be another select on that page with the "week2veganquantity" id, perhaps due to copy/paste.  If so, jQuery will find both and concatenate them into one string in your console.  If this is the case the solution would be to give each select a unique id.

Here is a link to a codepen where I was able to recreate this behavior:
http://codepen.io/amartin007/pen/MeaXBJ